# Neutering's effect

Tags: cats, desexing

Does neutered give any negative effect on the cat? He already have spraying problem. Some people say that it make them more passive.

Comment: I had a male cat that never started spraying before I had him neutered, but sprayed once in the presence of a female in heat. He was kind of freaked out by it, poor guy.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, if he was neutered before spraying it would have prevented him from starting however now that you neutered him a bit late he may never stop.

The whole passive thing is a myth, he will still be the same.